# Temporary display full name of argument instead of short name/abbrev

Tags: linux, shell, autocomplete, arguments, syntax

After an command, where the user should give an output location with `-o`, I wondered if there is an (standard) command that temporary displays the full name of the given argument, like the `-o`, that will temporary displayed as: `--output` (the full name) (instead of the `-o`).
For example; if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (just an example) is keep being pressed; the full name of the argument is displayed. Thus `-o` will be displayed as `--output`.

This in order to make sense of arguments of an command, without actually displaying the full name in the command itself. As something that is parsed...

E.g:

> youtube-dl -o

will become (temporary, by holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for example)

> youtube-dl  --output

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Since:

- There's no rule at all regarding short and long options correspondence
- There's no rule regarding the output that should be provided by a `--help` or `--usage`

It's quite impossible to implement such a behaviour automatically.
Instead, you should implement, for *every* commands the mapping. Then, with shells such as `zsh` you probably may implement this behaviour...

Comment: I understand that an "full"option display for all commands (wheter internal or via an external application) is difficult to realise.
However, do you know of something within Zsh/bash (or whatever shell) that can (somewhat) accomplice this?

Or do I just have to manually add this to mapping (and if so; can someone point me in the right direction?)

Comment: On my debian 10, using `zsh` if i launch  `zsh` and then type `ls -<tab><tab>`, zsh outputs the full list of options with short option/long option/option description. May it'es enought to fit your needs ...